# Pruebas con Junit

Tags: java, junit

Buenas tengo que hacer unas pruebas con `JUnit` pero es raro por que trae `exception`

Este es el método:

```
public double calcularTotal(int IVA, double total) throws Exception{
    if(total<0) throw new Exception("Error en total");
    if(IVA==REDUCIDO) return total*iva_red;
    else if(IVA==NORMAL) return total*iva_norm;
    else throw new Exception("Error en IVA");
}
```

Este es mi test:

```
public void testCalculoTotalV1() throws Exception{
    System.out.println("comprueba metodo Calculototal");
    int iva = 0;
    double total =0;
    Factura instance = new Factura();
    Class<Exception> expResult = Exception.class;
    double result = instance.calcularTotal(iva, total);
    assertEquals(expResult, result);
}
```

Pero da error al iniciar, dice:

> no runable methods

Comment: He editado la pregunta mejorándola, échale un vistazo y sobre todo, cuando pongas un código de error copia y pégalo, comprueba que este correcto ahora.

Comment: No runnable methods lo he visto solo cuando tratas de correr una clase sin main, sin más información de tu clase no te podremos ayudar. saludos.